# Strange use of "es" in "der Prozess"

Tags: grammar-identification

> Wenn man dich ansieht, möchte man fast dem Sprichwort glauben: „Einen solchen Prozeß haben, heißt ihn schon verloren haben.“ „Lieber Onkel,“ sagte K., „die Aufregung ist so unnütz, sie ist es auf deiner Seite und wäre es auch auf meiner. -[Referanz](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/69327/pg69327-images.html)

What does "es" refer to in the above sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word “es” refers to “unnütz”.

Comment: Interesting, so in a way, unnuetz aspect of the Aufregung is being referred by the usage of es

Comment: Yes. That's a common way to refer back to some procedure (here: unnütz sein) mentioned in an earlier sentence (part).

Comment: To add to that: the equivalent in English would be something like "it is so" or "it is that". In German you can just use a personal pronoun to refer an adjective which doesn't sound good in English.